# Excel 2010 VBA 'If' Flow Right to Left versus Left to Right

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to check a worksheet for the presence of special characters (specifically pipe '|' and double quotes '"').

In this scenario, there are '|' characters in both column A and B. When I search starting in column A, then Column B, the macro only detects the presence of the special character in the first column and skips the second, as shown.

```
        If (.Cells(r, 1) = "|" Or .Cells(r, 1) = """") And pass39 = "0" Then
        Cells(r, 1).Select
        UserForm57.Show vbModeless
        Exit Sub
        End If

        If (.Cells(r, 2) = "|" Or .Cells(r, 2) = """") And pass40 = "0" Then
        Cells(r, 2).Select
        UserForm58.Show vbModeless
        Exit Sub
        End If
```

When I search starting with column B, it detects special characters, first B then A.

```
        If (.Cells(r, 2) = "|" Or .Cells(r, 2) = """") And pass40 = "0" Then
        Cells(r, 2).Select
        UserForm58.Show vbModeless
        Exit Sub
        End If

        If (.Cells(r, 1) = "|" Or .Cells(r, 1) = """") And pass39 = "0" Then
        Cells(r, 1).Select
        UserForm57.Show vbModeless
        Exit Sub
        End If
```

Is there a way to detect the special character in A then B? To maybe offer some clarification, the second scenario works the way I want, and detects the characters the way I want, but detects column B first, then column A.

Comment: In each case the `Exit Sub` will always exit your code as soon as one match is made.  Maybe I'm not following exactly what you're asking here though: I don't see how the second scenario would ever make a match in ColA if it first gets a match in ColB ?

Comment: `UserForm57` and `UserForm58`?  If there are really 56 other ones, I'm guessing a refactor is in order...